# In VSCode I'm unable to get PHP debugger running properly

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-code, xdebug, unc

I am trying to create a new report for my job's database. 
Attempting to debug PHP in VSCode on Windows 10, running XAMPP on the local machine.
The site is in vue.js with a php api connecting to mysql 5.7 database. I use npm run dev for the crm in \khcc2\NETFOLDERS\UserName\htdocs\crm and need to debug the report.class.php api.

In php.ini

```
    [XDebug]
    zend_extension = C:\tempx\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
    xdebug.remote_enable = 1
    xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
    xdebug.remote_host = localhost
    xdebug.idekey = "vscode"
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

In the api I have launch.json

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
    }
```

I've tried adding to the launch.json each of these (not all at once):

```
    "cwd": "\\\\khcc2\\NETFOLDERS\\UserName\\htdocs\\api",
    "cwd": "h:\\htdocs\\api",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
```

and I sill get:
Unable to open 'index.php': File not found (file:///h:/htdocs/api/NETFOLDERS/UserName/htdocs/api/index.php).

Comment: Are you trying to debug a command-line script? If so, does the default value (`"cwd": "${fileDirname}"`) work? Otherwise, you're using the wrong configuration, it's `"Listen for XDebug"` what you really want (not `"Launch currently open script"`).

Comment: Yes, as the site is launched in npm I have to listen for it. But it seems to always check the wrong spot. I have the h: drive pointing to \\khcc2\netfolders\username\. I thought I needed cwd because it is looking in the wrong spot

Comment: Without cwd I get Unable to open 'index.php': File not found (file:///NETFOLDERS/username/htdocs/api/index.php).

Comment: Do you mean that you launch your command-line script from Node (e.g. with [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html))? Are you setting the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` environment variable?

Comment: edited the question to add detail